# How would Pythagorean's theorem work in higher dimensions? (General Question)

Tags: geometry

So for example when dealing with two dimensions you would use $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ and for three dimensions you would use $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2$ (Say for example you are calculating the length of the diagonal of a box) but what about in the fourth dimension? (Not really sure if there is a fourth dimension or how that even works in math so correct me if that makes no sense to say) Wouldn't it be something like $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = e^2$ ?

Comment: In any finite dimensional inner product space (Euclidian space) you can use a formula that resemebles the 2d case, and it is easy to prove using induction and inner product.

In infinite dimensional spaces, things get messy. The analogous formula is Parseval identity.

Comment: A similar question with answers explaining the theorem with graphics: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2837230/pythagorean-theorem-in-higher-dimensions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given two points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ and $y = (y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)$ we can define an $m$-dimensional "hyperbox" where $m\leq n$:

$$Box(x,y) := \{z = (z_1, z_2, \ldots , z_n)\mid z_i = t_i\cdot x_i + (1-t_i)\cdot y_i,\ t_i\in [0,1]\}$$

Where the lengths of its edges are $a_1:=|x_1-y_1|,\ a_2:=|x_2 - y_2|,\ \ldots\ ,\  a_n:=|x_n-y_n|$.

The length of the largest diagonal of said box is precisely the distance between $x$ and $y$:

$$d = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k-y_k)^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2}$$

Comment: I don't understand the construction of your box. $t$ is a scalar, $x_i$ and $y_i$ are components, so $t \cdot x_i$ is a real number, as is $(1-t) \cdot y_i$, as is their sum. so $z$ is a sum of real numbers. So the box is a set of real numbers. How does that describe a box in $m$ dimensions?

Comment: @user3578468 sorry, that $(z_1 + z_2 + \ldots + z_n)$ was supposed to be $(z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n)$. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

That is right. One well-known application of this fact is the Euclidian norm $\| \mathbf x \|$ for a vector $\mathbf x \in \Bbb R^n$, which is defined as
$$ \| \mathbf x \| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2+\dots+ x_n^2}.$$ This is exactly the generalization of the Pythagorean theorem you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Mathematicians are very happy in any number of dimensions - even infinite dimensions!
Another way to extend Pythagoras is to take a solid rectangular box, and slice off a corner.  The corner has three sides that were part of the old box; and one diagonal side.  The areas of these sides also obey $a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$.

Comment: The sliced-off-corner-of-a-rectangular-box version is [de Gua's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua%27s_theorem); importantly for this discussion, that result *also* generalizes to arbitrary dimensions in a natural way (with the dimensions of the "leg" and "hypotenuse" elements increasing at every stage). *Non-Euclidean* geometry, too, has counterpart relations, but [I'm aware only of the ones in dimensions 2 and 3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406966/famous-problems-where-we-only-know-the-elementary/508573#508573). (I discovered the $3$-dimensional case myself.)

Answer (score 0):

The length of a diagonal of a cube is square root of 3 times the length of a side. This is in three dimensions. I don't see how you arrive at this answer using a^2 + b^2 + c^2 though. Instead, you use a two dimensional slice with one side being square root of 2 times side and the other value the side length. Here d^2 = a^2 + b^2 which, with side being s equals sqrt((sqrt(2)s^2) + (s^2)) = sqrt(3)s = d. By extension, my guess of a four dimensional cube of length of side s would be e = sqrt( (sqrt(3)s^2) + (sqrt(2)s^2) + (s^2) ) which equals sqrt(6)s. I am not sure of this extension, however and unfortunately cannot prove this guess. After further analysis, a four dimensional cube of side equals 1 has diagonal of length sqrt(4) or 2.