# How can one prove this generalization?

Tags: vector-spaces, infinity

In two dimensional space, the length of a vector is $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

In three dimensional space, the length of a vector is $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

How can one prove that in n th dimensional space the length of a vector is

$$\sqrt{d_1^2+d_1^2+\cdots +d_n^2}$$

where $d_n$ represents the n dimensional axis, like $n_1=x, n_2=y, n_3=z, etc$

Comment: This is actually the definition of the length of a vector in $\Bbb R^n$. How do you define it if this property is what you are trying to prove?

Comment: The above is *only* one of an infinite number of possible ways to *Define* length of vector. WHat's your definition?

Comment: Also known as the "Euclidean norm:"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm

The multidimensional definition satisfies the requirements of a norm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition

Comment: If you assume that distance is defined so that the Pythagorean Theorem holds in two-dimensional subspaces, then there is a straightforward induction proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Pythagorean theorem for higher dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1588813/201168), one can show that the length of a point $\mathrm{P}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ from the origin in $\mathbf{R}^n$ is precisely equal to, $$\big\lVert\vec{\mathrm{OP}}\big\lVert=\operatorname{dist}(\mathrm{O},\mathrm{P})=\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n d_k^2}.$$

Comment: Precisely what I what looking for! Thank you.

Comment: @Research You're welcome! ;-)