# Can we generalize geometry and trigonometry to $n$ dimensions?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Generally geometry and trigonometry are the visual areas of mathematics. So, it is readily used in $1,2$ and $3$ dimensions.

However generalization in mathematics has its on beauty. Can we generalize circles, squares, etc. or the trigonometric functions to $n$ dimensional Euclidean space?

Comment: Sure. For example, the $n$-sphere: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere. Also, this might be of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_trigonometry

Comment: Thats nice, but doesnt that defeat the purpose of geometry being visual?

Comment: Not everyone would agree that the purpose of geometry is visual,

Comment: But doesn't geometrical questions need critical visualization to be solved? Consider this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkmNXy7er84&t=332s

Comment: @SanjiVinsmoke Not always. Moreover, with some training one develops ability to visualize in higher dimensions (even infinite dimensions).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For example, the generalisation of a triangle is an $n$-simplex in $\Bbb{R}^n$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex.

Results from trigonometry such as the Law of Sines and the Law of Cosines can be extended to $n$-simplices.

Comment: Is the Pythagoras theorem also valid in higher dimensions? If so, is there a proof, for higher dimensions?

Comment: Yes, it is. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588798/how-would-pythagoreans-theorem-work-in-higher-dimensions-general-question and for the proof, see http://www.cs.bc.edu/~alvarez/NDPyt.pdf.