# Generalized Pythagorean Theorem?

Tags: geometry, vectors

So we’re all familiar with the famous Pythagorean Theorem for a right angled 2D triangles, which can be written as $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ ($x$ is the base, $y$ is the height, $r$ is the hypotenuse).

There exists another formula for 3D triangles that can be written as $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =r^2$.

Given the pattern here in dimensions, does there exist a 4D Pythagorean theorem, $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 = r^2$? Is there a general Pythagorean theorem than applies for n dimensions, $x_1^2 +x_2^2 +x_3^2 + x_4^2 +…+x_n^2 =r^2$?

If so, how can we prove it if we can’t use any geometry?

And if not, for which dimensions does this Pythagorean pattern hold true?

Comment: I think the "theorem" is taken as the *definition* of length in higher dimensions. The distance from the origin to $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ is defined to be $\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}$.

Comment: The distance formula (calculating the square of a length from the squares of perpendicular lengths) certainly generalizes to $n$ dimensions. Perhaps more interestingly, [de Gua's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua%27s_theorem) in three dimensions relates squares of *areas*; this idea generalizes to $n$ dimensions, with the dimensions of the quantities involved increasing at each stage. (Lengths in $2$ dimensions; areas in $3$ dimensions; volumes in $4$ dimensions; etc, etc, etc.)

Comment: *"[H]ow can we prove it if we can’t use any geometry?"* This is a benefit of *coordinate* geometry (and linear algebra, etc). It lets us exploit algebra to explore geometry we can't "see".

Comment: @GerryMyerson but you can prove this inductively purely geometrically. So the "definition" is really a codification the the Euclidean $n$-dimensional result.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588798/how-would-pythagoreans-theorem-work-in-higher-dimensions-general-question